# Duplicate class names after using Webpack in production mode with Uglify's keep_fnames

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs

I'm working on a library that relies on `Function.prototype.name` a lot (to set shortcuts on the parent instance).

```
class FooSection {}
class BarSection {}

class Page {
  constructor(sections) {
    for (let SectionClass of sections) {
      this[SectionClass.name] = new SectionClass(this);
    }
  }
}

let page = new Page([
  FooSection,
  BarSection
]);
```

This works all fine and dandy, until mangling from Webpack's optimization kicks in. That mangles function names by default, resulting in classes and their `name` property being shortened. Useful usually, not here. So I went and passed the appropriate configuration to Webpack:

```
// ...
optimization: {
  minimizer: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin( {
                          uglifyOptions: {
                            keep_fnames: true
                          }
                        } )
  ]
}
```

According to the documentation, this should preserve my function names. Astonishingly, what happens is that the names are *duplicated* instead, so `Page` becomes `Page_Page` suddenly (*note: this code block is written by me, but that's  roughly what the output looks like*):

```
class FooSection_FooSection{}
class BarSection_BarSection{}
class Page_Page{
  constructor(t) {
    for(let s of t){this[s.name]=new s(this)}
  }
}
let p=new Page_Page([FooSection_FooSection,BarSection_BarSection])
```

This is not reproducible using UglifyJS alone, so it must be somewhere inside the toolchain (webpack -> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin -> uglifyjs), but I can't figure out where. Has anyone experienced this yet?

Versions as follows:

- webpack: 4.6.0
- uglifyjs-webpack-plugin: 1.2.5
- uglifyjs: 3.3.9

**Update:**
As per the comments, the same issue seems to occur using the TerserPlugin uglifier.

Comment: @Piterden unfortunately I never figured that out and resorted with an alternative approach in the end... Must've take you quite a while to find that esoteric issue here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty old topic, but I just put it here for reference as I stumbled upon the same issue and finally found out the reason.

This behavior is caused by webpack's [ModuleConcatenationPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-concatenation-plugin/) that moves all modules into a global scope for performance reasons. That might cause name conflicts and thus, webpack renames the classes and prefixes them with their file/module names.

You can disable this behavior by setting `concatenateModules` to `false` in your webpack config.

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    concatenateModules: false
  }
};
```

Since this is not a bug and you're writing a library, it's probably not a good idea to rely on this behavior though.